# Quando devemos usar referências nas perguntas/respostas?

Tags: debate

Surgiu hoje um debate no chat do site a respeito de quando devemos usar referências à artigos ou documentação em perguntas ou respostas, visto que alguns usuários as vezes parecem colocar referências fora de contexto.

Há ainda aqueles que dão uma respostinha pequena, com um link para uma publicação, e finalmente, tivemos no passado problemas com artigos copiados cuja a referência foi colocada ao final da resposta (que mesmo com a referência, ainda sim estava errado a cópia, por conta dos Direitos Autorais).

Meu objetivo aqui é ter uma forma prática de usar as referências aqui.

Então, me atrevi a fazer alguns questionamentos:

- Quando devemos usar links para referenciar manuais ou artigos? Essa pergunta é algo que pode demandar opinião, mas se chegamos a bons argumentos, poderão ajudar usuários que estão iniciando ou dificuldade para saber a hora certa de usar.
- Quando eu devo evitar referências?
- Em algum momento, as referências podem ser prejudiciais para a pergunta/resposta feita no site?
- Referências em inglês, realmente agregam algum valor a uma comunidade que procura respostas em português?

Comment: Referências são sempre boas a não ser que ela não tenha nada a ver com a pergunta, ou esteja lá só para parecer que a pessoa fez pesquisa, tem um ponto relevante, sem ser. A referência é ruim quando ela desvia o foco da pergunta, adiciona algo desnecessário ou mesmo enganoso. É difícil listar casos, depende de cada caso. Essa perguntas nasceu por outro motivo. Houve uma enxurrada de perguntas nada claras, muitas vezes ampla e que usavam referências para parecer perguntas bem escritas.

Comment: Apesar de ser louvável o esforço, ter a referência ou não não é o problema, é ela não ajudar no entendimento da pergunta. Se a pergunta ficar clara talvez seja irrelevante se tem referência ou não.

Comment: @bigown não tivemos já esta discussão no meta?

Comment: @JorgeB. não me lembro.

Comment: @Wallece eu coloco sempre referência quando estou a escrever uma resposta baseada ou com influência numa fonte. Ou então quando é uma coisa que está no manual especifico.

Comment: My two cents: Sempre uso referências. Geralmente linko diretamente o artigo em um conceito ou palavra. Quando essa estratégia não funciona eu uso "veja mais detalhes nesse artigo" entre parêntesis. Finalmente, quando a resposta é enorme, com links para assuntos amplos eu incluo uma seção dedicada a referências repetindo os principais links no corpo do texto (veja [um exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/153048/100)). A idéia é evitar ser formal demais em respostas pequenas, porém abrir espaço para que outros usuários sigam a trilha de pesquisa que te levou a determinada conclusão.

Answer (score 7):

Vamos as perguntas:

> Quando devemos usar links para referenciar manuais ou artigos? Essa pergunta é algo que pode demandar opinião, mas se chegamos a bons argumentos, poderão ajudar usuários que estão iniciando ou dificuldade para saber a hora certa de usar.

Perguntas elaboradas , respostas elaboradas, as vezes muitos manuais e artigos "desconhecidos" até então contém informações muito valiosas para responder a pergunta e duvidas futuras ligadas a ela. Perguntas com respostas do tipo *" basta você alterar aqui aqui e aqui"* não é o caso. Apenas com um pouco de conhecimento seu, foi suficiente para alterar, não necessariamente precisou de uma introdução toda para explicar.

Outro ponto são perguntas teóricas, a maioria das perguntas teóricas precisam de uma fonte para escrever de maneira coerente, temos uma tag [terminologia](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/terminologia) com perguntas deste estilo e quase todas tem algum referencial.

> Quando eu devo evitar referências?

Acredito que o único exemplo cabível é perguntas com respostas muito curtas
como citei antes. Perguntas que não precisam de elaboração de conteúdo muito grande, não necessita de um livro ou um tcc, as vezes um link no máximo já é o suficiente, ou nem isso pois com alterações simples já respondeu e você não precisou de nada, apenas do próprio conhecimento. Todos os outros tipos cabem referências, claro que nem sempre será usado, alguns usuários dominam quase que completamente informações relativas a pergunta

> Referências em inglês, realmente agregam algum valor a uma comunidade que procura respostas em português?

Sim! Muita! trabalhamos com programação, e é em inglês todos os comandos das principais linguagens, o minimo que podemos  esperar é que as melhores referencias estejam na linguá padrão.

Existem muitos casos de referencias muito bem traduzidas e produzidas por brasileiros, mas se comparar com a quantidade em outra linguagem é quase comparar um livro com uma biblioteca inteira.

Não necessariamente precisa saber tudo de inglês, eu assim como muitos usuários temos uma certa dificuldade, entretanto nem por isso vou deixar de procurar referencias de locais com mais conteúdo. O SOEN por exemplo é lotado de boas perguntas(e de más também).

Claro não podemos esquecer, algumas citações são protegidas por direitos autorais. Livros e trabalhos acadêmicos são diferentes, pois o intuito é promover e compartilhar o conhecimento. Sem referencia é fraude, com referencia significa que você usou para descrever seu artigo(resposta), agora artigos sob essa licença não podem ser reproduzidos da mesma forma, a ocasião que irá dizer.